# awk - numbering the match occurrence is not working correctly

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to highlight each occurrence of the match word, using the below awk command,

Input:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Command:

```
python -c 'import this' |  awk -v t="better" ' { gsub(t,"[" "&-" ++a["&"] "]" ,$0); print } '
```

but it looks like the gsub() is not working correctly. The input has total 8 - "better" match, but for the last one the above command prints "better-18". How to fix this.

```
Although never is often [better-18] than *right* now.. # wrong should be 8
```

Expected output:

```
Beautiful is [better-1] than ugly.
Explicit is [better-2] than implicit.
Simple is [better-3] than complex.
Complex is [better-4] than complicated.
Flat is [better-5] than nested.
Sparse is [better-6] than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is [better-7] than never.
Although never is often [better-8] than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

I would like to have an extendable solution that could accommodate more words, i.e input from another text file, with just one scanning of the input file. The "word" should be full match not partial/substring.

match.txt

```
better
idea
```

Comment: it would help (us) if you provided the raw data generated by the `python ... ` call; in the meantime ... when I run your code I'm finding the output shows up as `[[better-NR]]`, so there are a couple issues ... 1) need to work on the `[...]` processing and 2) regardless of whether or not the line contains a `better` you are **always** running `gsub(.... ++a ...)` so (effectively) `a==NR`

Comment: yes.. updated the question. If you just issue ````python -c 'import this'```` you can get the input

Comment: if the answer is extendable for more words, it would be nice.. so I mentioned like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do:

```
gsub(t,"[" "&-" ++a["&"] "]" ,$0)
```

because it'll do a partial regexp match instead of a full string match and, more importantly, the arguments to `gsub()` are evaluated before `gsub()` is called so the `++a["&"]` is incrementing the value of `a[]` indexed by the literal single character string `"&"` before `gsub()` is called. It's exactly the same as if you wrote:

```
foo=(++a["&"]); gsub(t,"[" "&-" foo "]" ,$0)
```

This might be what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for `patsplit()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    words[$1]
    next
}
{
    n = patsplit($0,flds,/[[:alnum:]_]+/,seps)
    out = seps[0]
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        word = flds[i]
        if ( word in words ) {
             word = "[" word "-" (++cnt[word]) "]"
        }
        out = out word seps[i]
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk match.txt file
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is [better-1] than ugly.
Explicit is [better-2] than implicit.
Simple is [better-3] than complex.
Complex is [better-4] than complicated.
Flat is [better-5] than nested.
Sparse is [better-6] than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is [better-7] than never.
Although never is often [better-8] than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad [idea-1].
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good [idea-2].
Namespaces are one honking great [idea-3] -- let's do more of those!
```

The above assumes your definition of a "word" is any sequence of alphanumeric-or-underscore (i.e. "word-constituent") characters - if not then just change `[[:alnum:]_]+` to whatever matches your definition of a "word".

You can do the same in any POSIX awk with a `while (match(..,/[[:alnum:]_]+/)) substr(...` loop - left as an exercise if you want that.

If you wanted to handle 1 word passed as a variable assignment then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    n = patsplit($0,flds,/[[:alnum:]_]+/,seps)
    out = seps[0]
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        word = flds[i]
        if ( word == t ) {
             word = "[" word "-" (++cnt) "]"
        }
        out = out word seps[i]
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -v t='better' -f tst.awk file
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is [better-1] than ugly.
Explicit is [better-2] than implicit.
Simple is [better-3] than complex.
Complex is [better-4] than complicated.
Flat is [better-5] than nested.
Sparse is [better-6] than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is [better-7] than never.
Although never is often [better-8] than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: thank you.. still not clear on gsub(), if the args are evaluated before it is called, then how "&-"  works when there is match?.. if I use simply ````a[&]```` im getting error

Comment: When you call any function `foo("&")` the argument passed to `foo()` is the string `"&"`. When  you call `foo(++a["&"])` the argument passed to `foo()` is the result of incrementing the value stored in the array `a[]` indexed by the string `"&"`, i.e. the result of `++a["&"]`. In that regard `gsub()` is no different from any other function. Yes, you can't index an array by a symbol like `&`, just by a string (or a number which gets converted to a string).

Comment: I should probably add in case it's not clear that **within gsub()** the character `&` in a string passed as the second argument gets converted to the string that matched the regexp passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple match words, Perl can also be used

```
$ perl -pe ' BEGIN { @m= map {chomp;$_} qx(cat match.txt); $t=join("\|",@m) }; \
s/$t/$kv{$&}++;"[$&-$kv{$&}]"/ge ' input.txt
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is [better-1] than ugly.
Explicit is [better-2] than implicit.
Simple is [better-3] than complex.
Complex is [better-4] than complicated.
Flat is [better-5] than nested.
Sparse is [better-6] than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is [better-7] than never.
Although never is often [better-8] than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad [idea-1].
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good [idea-2].
Namespaces are one honking great [idea-3] -- let's do more of those!
```